# Regex para encontrar texto entre colchetes

Tags: python, regex

Estou tentando criar uma regex para identificar a seguinte ocorrência:

```
[Ticket: 20021501280806]
```

Preciso de uma expressão que identifique o número do ticket, porém, apenas dentro da string `[Ticket: ]`.

Atualmente fiz o seguinte:

```
r'[Ticket: (\d+)]'
```

Mas não deu certo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os colchetes possuem significado especial em regex: eles criam uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Por exemplo, `[abc]` significa "a letra `a` **ou** a letra `b` **ou** a letra `c`" (qualquer uma delas).

Sendo assim, a expressão `[Ticket: (\d+)]` é uma classe de caracteres que significa "a letra `T` **ou** a letra `i` **ou** a letra `c`, etc..." - o detalhe é que toda essa expressão **corresponde a apenas um caractere** (qualquer um que esteja entre as opções que estão dentro dos colchetes).

> *Além disso, muitos [meta-caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) (aqueles que possuem algum significado especial em regex) "perdem seus poderes" quando estão dentro dos colchetes. Por isso, nesta regex, os parênteses e o sinal de mais significam literalmente os caracteres `(`, `)` e `+`, o que quer dizer que esta regex também encontrará um match se a string for algo como `+()`, por exemplo - [veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/pWp2wI/2/) um exemplo.*

Enfim, para que a regex considere literalmente os caracteres `[` e `]`, basta escapá-los com `\`. Então a regex deve ser `\[Ticket: (\d+)\]`.

---

#### Opções para encontrar os *matches*

Não ficou claro se a string possui várias ocorrências de `"[Ticket: (números)]"` e você quer encontrar todas, ou se esse trecho só ocorre uma vez. De qualquer forma, vamos ver algumas opções.

Se há várias ocorrências deste texto e você quer capturar todas, pode usar [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.findall), que retorna uma lista com todas as ocorrências:

```
import re

texto = 'lorem ipsum [Ticket: 20021501280806] blablabla [Ticket: 123456789] etc [Ticket: 987654] xyz.'
r = re.compile(r'\[Ticket: (\d+)\]')
matches = r.findall(texto)

print(matches) # ['20021501280806', '123456789', '987654']
```

<sup>[Veja o código rodando no IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/4na3eD)</sup>

No caso, o trecho contendo os números (`\d+`) está entre parênteses, o que forma um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). E quando a regex possui grupos de captura, `findall` retorna somente eles. Por isso a lista já retorna somente os números.

Se quiser, não precisa usar `compile` e pode usar a regex diretamente:

```
matches = re.findall(r'\[Ticket: (\d+)\]', texto)
```

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile), o uso de `compile` é mais eficiente se a mesma regex é usada várias vezes no mesmo programa. Fica a seu critério escolher qual usar. Ver também: [Por que utilizar uma expressão regular "compilada" (re.compile) em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/486258/112052)

---

Outra opção é usar [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.finditer), que retorna um [iterador](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter) contendo os *matches*:

```
import re

texto = 'lorem ipsum [Ticket: 20021501280806] blablabla [Ticket: 123456789] etc [Ticket: 987654] xyz.'
r = re.compile(r'\[Ticket: (\d+)\]')

for match in r.finditer(texto):
    print(match.group(1))
```

<sup>[Veja o código rodando no IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/fVKgnx)</sup>

A cada iteração do `for`, é retornado um [`Match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) contendo informações sobre o trecho que foi encontrado. Como a informação que me interessa é a que está no grupo de captura, eu uso o [método `group`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) para obtê-lo. E como o trecho `(\d+)` é o primeiro par de parênteses da regex, então ele é o primeiro grupo de captura (o grupo 1), por isso eu faço `match.group(1)` para obter o trecho que foi capturado. A cada iteração do `for`, o *match* contém uma das ocorrências encontradas. A saída é:

```
20021501280806
123456789
987654
```

A diferença entre as duas abordagens acima é que `findall` retorna uma lista com todas as ocorrências encontradas, enquanto `finditer` retorna um [*iterador*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter), que carrega apenas um *match* por vez a cada iteração. Caso hajam muitas ocorrências a serem encontradas, `finditer` gastará bem menos memória (por não carregar todos os *matches* de uma vez), além de não buscar todas as ocorrências se o *loop* for interrompido, por exemplo (já `findall` sempre precisa carregar todas as ocorrências para retornar a lista).

E assim como `findall`, você também pode usar `finditer` sem precisar chamar `compile` antes:

```
for match in re.finditer(r'\[Ticket: (\d+)\]', texto):
    print(match.group(1))
```

---

Se o texto só ocorre uma vez - ou se ele ocorre várias vezes, mas você só quer a primeira ocorrência - pode usar [`search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search):

```
import re

texto = 'lorem ipsum [Ticket: 20021501280806] blablabla [Ticket: 123456789] etc [Ticket: 987654] xyz.'
r = re.compile(r'\[Ticket: (\d+)\]')

match = r.search(texto)
if match:
    print(match.group(1)) # 20021501280806
```

<sup>[Veja o código rodando no IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/VNcZd0)</sup>

Neste caso ele encontra a primeira ocorrência da regex no texto, ignorando as demais. E assim como as opções acima, também existe a opção de usar `search` diretamente, sem chamar `compile` antes:

```
match = re.search(r'\[Ticket: (\d+)\]', texto)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

Answer (score 4):

O problema é que na sua string há colchetes, que são caracteres especiais em regex, como você pode ver aqui na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Para resolver este problema, você deve retirar esses colchetes da sua string ou então utilizar no *pattern* o caractere `\` antes dos colchetes, para dizer ao regex que ele não deve ser considerado um caractere especial. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
string = "[Ticket: 20021501280806]"
re.findall(r'\[Ticket: (\d+)\]', string)
```