# Por que utilizar uma expressão regular "compilada" (re.compile) em Python?

Tags: python, regex

Em uma [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/486252/69296) deste site, reparei que, embora as duas respostas fizessem uso de expressões regulares, caminhos diferentes foram tomados:

- Uma delas utilizou a função [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) para realizar a operação de busca.
- A outra utilizou a função [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) para, como entendo, *criar* uma expressão regular compilada e, a partir do objeto retornado, utilizar um método como `search`.

Diante dessa situação, fico com algumas dúvidas:

- O que seria uma expressão regular "compilada" (conforme o nome da função sugere)?
- Qual a vantagem de utilizar expressões regulares desse jeito?
- Há alguma desvantagem?

Comment: boa pergunta Luiz, entretanto antes de alguém responder podes ir satisfazendo a curiosidade: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452104/is-it-worth-using-pythons-re-compile

Comment: Hehe, já cheguei a ver, mas decidi trazer pra cá, acabei aproveitando o gatilho da outra pergunta. :D

Comment: Fizeste bem, não temos referência a isto no SOpt

Comment: Como não tenho conhecimento suficiente para responder sua pergunta por completo irei apenas comentar, Não são exatamente as expressões que são compiladas, mas sim a maioria das operações e seus padrões. Como o assunto de RE está muito ligado a compiladores, não seria tão computacionalmente viável executar a maioria dessas operações em alto nível, por isso a fim de optimização, esses padrões e operações são compilados em bytecodes e por baixo dos panos executados em C. Com isso, talvez o processo não seja tão perfeitamente ajustado. Mas é mais ou menos assim que acontece.

Comment: @JoaoRobertoMendes A expressão é compilada sim, e transformada em uma instância de [`re.Pattern`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re-objects)

Comment: Relacionado: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/410008

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Toda expressão regular, seja em Python ou qualquer outra linguagem, é compilada: é feito o *parsing* para saber se a sintaxe está correta, se a expressão é válida, para obter todos os seus *tokens*, etc (os detalhes, claro, podem variar de acordo com a implementação). No fim, tudo é transformado em alguma estrutura interna, contendo todas as informações necessárias para que ela possa fazer o *matching*.

No caso do Python, uma regex compilada resulta em uma instância de [`re.Pattern`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re-objects).

---

[Segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile), o funcionamento - usando `compile` antes ou apenas `match` direto - será similar. Ou seja, as 2 formas abaixo funcionarão da mesma forma:

```
prog = re.compile(pattern)
result = prog.match(string)

# ou
result = re.match(pattern, string)
```

O mesmo vale para os métodos `search`, `findall`, etc. Todos tem a opção de receber a expressão como parâmetro, ou poder ser chamada a partir da regex pré-compilada.

A diferença que a documentação cita é:

> *but using `re.compile()` and saving the resulting regular expression object for reuse is more efficient when the expression will be used several times in a single program.*

Ou seja, usar `compile` é mais eficiente caso a expressão seja reusada várias vezes. Mas no caso de usar apenas uma vez, não fará diferença significativa.

Só que a mesma documentação também diz o seguinte:

> *The compiled versions of the most recent patterns passed to `re.compile()` and the module-level matching functions are cached, so programs that use only a few regular expressions at a time needn’t worry about compiling regular expressions.*

Ou seja, as expressões mais recentes são *cacheadas* internamente, então programas que usam poucas expressões e/ou não reusam tanto não devem se preocupar muito com isso.

E só lembrando que no fim, **a expressão sempre é compilada**, o que muda é quando isso acontece: `re.match(expressao, string)` acaba compilando a expressão, caso ela não esteja no já mencionado *cache*.

---

[Nesta pergunta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/452104) há várias respostas discutindo a respeito, e [uma delas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/453568) menciona a legibilidade que traz ao usar `compile`, pois pode deixar mais claro que aquela expressão será reusada várias vezes. Não vou repetir tudo que tem lá, mas é uma boa fonte para complementar o assunto.

---

Como curiosidade, fiz um teste rápido:

```
import re
texto = "# 44,739 % of all cache refs 12,345 lorem ipsum # 98,736 % etc 45,678 blablbla"
exp = r'# (\d+,\d+) %'

from timeit import timeit

# executa 1 milhão de vezes cada teste
params = { 'number' : 1000000, 'globals': globals() }

# usando a expressão compilada
print(timeit('r.findall(texto)', setup='r = re.compile(exp)', **params))
# não usando a expressão compilada
print(timeit('re.findall(exp, texto)', **params))
```

Na minha máquina, em média, a versão com `compile` demorou entre 0,5 e 0,8 segundos, enquanto a outra opção demorou entre 1,3 e 1,7 segundos. Ou seja, mesmo com o *cache* interno, usar `compile` ainda apresentou um ganho. Testando no [IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/zg7jte) e no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/RegexCompileOrNotCompile#main.py), os resultados foram similares (a versão com `compile` foi mais rápida).

Meu palpite é que isso ocorra porque `match` precisa fazer o *lookup* no cache, então mesmo que a regex já esteja lá, ainda tem esse custo adicional de procurá-la. Já usando `compile`, eu uso a instância pré-compilada diretamente, sem precisar procurar no cache.

Mas como sempre, o que vale no final é testar o seu caso específico para saber se faz diferença ou não.

---

#### Brincando um pouco com o cache

Só como curiosidade, fiz um pequeno teste com o cache (**atenção**, fiz isso no Python 3.7, então em versões diferentes isso pode não funcionar, já que depende de detalhes da implementação interna do módulo `re`, [que inclusive já mudou várias vezes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14757032)).

Enfim, no Python 3.7 o *cache* de regex é um dicionário, então primeiro criei uma subclasse de `dict`, para logar quando um elemento é adicionado ou obtido do mesmo:

```
class DictWatch(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        dict.__init__(self, args)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        val = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        print('obtendo item no cache:', key)
        return val

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        print(f'guardando item no cache: {key}={val}')
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, val)
```

E em seguida eu sobrescrevo o *cache*, e faço um teste inicial só para ver se ele funciona:

```
import re
re._MAXCACHE = 3 # mudar tamanho máximo para 3
re._cache = DictWatch() # sobrescreve o cache com meu dicionário acima

print('\ncompilar abc')
re.compile('abc')
print('cache:', re._cache.keys())

print('\ncompilar abcd')
re.compile('abcd')
print('cache:', re._cache.keys())

print('\ncompilar abc de novo')
re.compile('abc')
print('cache:', re._cache.keys())

print('\ncompilar abcde')
re.compile('abcde')
print('cache:', re._cache.keys())

print('\ncompilar abcdef')
re.compile('abcdef')
print('cache:', re._cache.keys())
```

A saída é:

```
compilar abc
guardando item no cache: (<class 'str'>, 'abc', 0)=re.compile('abc')
cache: dict_keys([(<class 'str'>, 'abc', 0)])

compilar abcd
guardando item no cache: (<class 'str'>, 'abcd', 0)=re.compile('abcd')
cache: dict_keys([(<class 'str'>, 'abc', 0), (<class 'str'>, 'abcd', 0)])

compilar abc de novo
obtendo item no cache: (<class 'str'>, 'abc', 0)
cache: dict_keys([(<class 'str'>, 'abc', 0), (<class 'str'>, 'abcd', 0)])

compilar abcde
guardando item no cache: (<class 'str'>, 'abcde', 0)=re.compile('abcde')
cache: dict_keys([(<class 'str'>, 'abc', 0), (<class 'str'>, 'abcd', 0), (<class 'str'>, 'abcde', 0)])

compilar abcdef
guardando item no cache: (<class 'str'>, 'abcdef', 0)=re.compile('abcdef')
cache: dict_keys([(<class 'str'>, 'abcd', 0), (<class 'str'>, 'abcde', 0), (<class 'str'>, 'abcdef', 0)])
```

Repare que ao compilar `abc` pela segunda vez, a regex é obtida do cache, pois ela já estava lá. E quando o tamanho máximo é atingido, `abc` é retirada, para que se coloque a última regex compilada.

Agora fazendo o teste com `re.match`:

```
import re
re._MAXCACHE = 3 # mudar tamanho máximo para 3
re._cache = DictWatch() # sobrescreve o cache com meu dicionário acima

print('match')
re.match('abc', 'xyz')
print('cache:', re._cache.keys())

print('\nmatch de novo')
re.match('abc', '123')
print('cache:', re._cache.keys())
```

A saída é:

```
match
guardando item no cache: (<class 'str'>, 'abc', 0)=re.compile('abc')
cache: dict_keys([(<class 'str'>, 'abc', 0)])

match de novo
obtendo item no cache: (<class 'str'>, 'abc', 0)
cache: dict_keys([(<class 'str'>, 'abc', 0)])
```

Indicando que na primeira vez que `re.match` é chamado, a regex é compilada e guardada no cache. Na segunda vez ela não é mais compilada, pois agora ela é obtida do cache.

Agora usando `compile`:

```
import re
re._MAXCACHE = 3 # mudar tamanho máximo para 3
re._cache = DictWatch() # sobrescreve o cache com meu dicionário acima

print('compile')
r = re.compile('abc')
print('cache:', re._cache.keys())

print('\nmatch')
r.match('xyz')
print('cache:', re._cache.keys())

print('\nre.match passando a regex compilada')
re.match(r, '123')
print('cache:', re._cache.keys())

print('\nre.match passando a regex como string')
re.match('abc', '123')
print('cache:', re._cache.keys())
```

A saída é:

```
compile
guardando item no cache: (<class 'str'>, 'abc', 0)=re.compile('abc')
cache: dict_keys([(<class 'str'>, 'abc', 0)])

match
cache: dict_keys([(<class 'str'>, 'abc', 0)])

re.match passando a regex compilada
cache: dict_keys([(<class 'str'>, 'abc', 0)])

re.match passando a regex como string
obtendo item no cache: (<class 'str'>, 'abc', 0)
cache: dict_keys([(<class 'str'>, 'abc', 0)])
```

Repare como o uso direto da instância pré-compilada não faz a busca no cache (mesmo se passarmos ela como parâmetro para `re.match`), enquanto se passarmos a expressão como uma string para `re.match`, a busca no cache é feita.