# Como fazer Split por Letras Maiúsculas e Números ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: python, string, regex, lista

Como posso separar uma string por letras e números ao mesmo tempo?

Por exemplo se eu tiver as strings:

```
composto1 = 'H2SO4'
composto2 = 'CaCO2'
composto3 = 'C20H17'
```

Já tentei fazer:

```
import re
list_composto1 = re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', composto1)
list_composto2 = re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', composto2)
list_composto3 = re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', composto3)
print(list_composto1 , list_composto2 , list_composto3)
```

output

```
['H2', 'S', 'O4'] ['Ca', 'C', 'O2'] ['C20', 'H17']
```

Porém só consegui separar pelas letras maiúsculas. Teria algum método para separar os números juntos e obter o resultado abaixo:

```
list_composto1 = ['H', '2', 'S', 'O', '4']
list_composto2 = ['Ca', 'C', 'O' , '2']
list_composto3 = ['C', '20', 'H', '17' ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seu critério é basicamente:

- uma letra maiúscula, seguida opcionalmente por uma minúscula, **ou**
- um ou mais números

Sendo assim, basta fazer:

```py
import re
r = re.compile(r'[A-Z][a-z]?|\d+')
composto1 = 'H2SO4'
composto2 = 'CaCO2'
composto3 = 'C20H17'
list_composto1 = r.findall(composto1)
list_composto2 = r.findall(composto2)
list_composto3 = r.findall(composto3)
print(list_composto1 , list_composto2 , list_composto3)
```

O `?` indica que a letra minúscula é [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html), e o `|` significa ["ou"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). Já o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d` significa "um dígito", e o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` indica "um ou mais".

Também usei `re.compile`, que [é recomendado quando você usa a mesma expressão várias vezes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/486258/112052).

Answer (score 5):

*Apenas por curiosidade.*
Também em Python é possível solucionar o problema sem recorrer a expressões regulares, iterando pelos caracteres e usando uma lista como [pilha](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilha_(inform%C3%A1tica)) para separar as partes da fórmula.

```
composto1 = 'SnBrCl3'
composto2 = 'C6H12O6'
composto3 = 'C7H5N3O6'


def qsplit(s):      
  stack = []                              #Inicializa a pilha de separação.
  result = []                             #Inicializa a lista de resultados.
  index= 0                                #Inicializa o índice indicando o caractere sendo iterado. 

  #Sub-rotina que joga os valores da pilha na lista de resultados e esvazia a pilha.
  def pop():
    result.append("".join(stack))         #Joga o valor da pilha na lista de resultados.
    stack.clear()                         #Esvazia a pilha.

  #Itera pelos caracteres da string s...
  while index < len(s):
    #...verifica se o caractere é letra maiúscula...
    if (val:= s[index]).isupper():        
      if len(stack)!=0: pop()             #...se a pilha não estiver vazia chama pop()
      stack.append(val)                   #...adiciona o caractere a pilha.
    #...verifica se o caractere é letra minúscula...
    elif val.islower():
      stack.append(val)                   #...adiciona o caractere a pilha.
      pop()                               #... chama a função pop().
    #...verifica se o caractere é um digito decimal...
    elif val.isdecimal():
      if len(stack) !=0 and not stack[-1].isdecimal(): pop() #...se a pilha não estiver vazia chama pop()
      stack.append(val)                   #...adiciona o caractere a pilha.
    else:
      print(f'Caractere {val} inválido.') #...caso o caractere não enquadre em nenhuma opção. 
    index += 1                            #incrementa o índice do caractere sendo iterado.
  else:
    pop()                                 #ao deixar o laço de iteração chama pop().
  return result

print(qsplit(composto1))                  #['Sn', 'Br', 'Cl', '3']
print(qsplit(composto2))                  #['C', '6', 'H', '12', 'O', '6']
print(qsplit(composto3))                  #['C', '7', 'H', '5', 'N', '3', 'O', '6']
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/QSplit#main.py)</sup>